# SEND A WAV FILE OVER UDP PROTOCOL

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I want to experiment and learn UDP protocol. So i started coding a server and a client send a .wav file  from client to server and output that on my headset as i receive samples. I encountered some very strange behaviour with the following code

**CLIENT**

```
import socket
import wave
import time as ti
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) 

server_address2 = ('192.168.0.196',40000)


BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

wf = wave.open(r'path\song.wav','rb')   

data = wf.readframes(BUFFER_SIZE)
print(len(data))
sent = sock.sendto(data,server_address2)


    #response,addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

while data!=b'':

        data = wf.readframes(BUFFER_SIZE)
        sent = sock.sendto(data,server_address2)    
        ti.sleep(0.04)
```

**SERVER**

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import socket 
import pyaudio
import time
import struct 
import wave 
import numpy as np

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = ('192.168.0.196',40000)
print('starting up on %s port %s' %(server_address, str(40000)))

sock.bind(server_address)


# BUFFER_SIZE = 1

# #OUTPUT FILE OPTIONS 


# # Opening audio file as binary data
wf = wave.open(r'path\song.wav', 'rb')

# # Instantiate PyAudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
file_sw = wf.getsampwidth()
# print(file_sw)
print("channels: " ,wf.getnchannels())
print("sampwidth: ",wf.getsampwidth())
print("framerate: " ,wf.getframerate())
print("p.get_format_from_width(file_sw): ", p.get_format_from_width(file_sw))

televizor = 7
casti = 5
stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(file_sw),
                channels=1,
                rate=22050,
                output_device_index=casti,
                output=True
                #stream_callback = callback
                )



#sock.settimeout(0.3)
while True:
    try:

        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048*2*2)     

        stream.write(data)
        print(data)





    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

The samples from the wav are transfered to the server and it sounds good for a second but then it speeds up and a 1 minute long song is over in 2 seconds

Even if i write time.sleep(any number) on the client to send those samples slower, it just gets faster and faster.. What is this behaviour ?

Comment: I don't know much about WAV files, but I suspect you need to do the timing on the server, not the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that your network is transporting the audio data to the server much faster than your server's audio card can play back the audio data.

Because of that (combined with the fact that UDP doesn't have any concept of flow-control), your server's incoming-UDP-packet buffer quickly fills up (while your server is blocked inside `stream.write(data)` waiting for a chunk of audio to play back), at which point any additional incoming UDP packets are silently discarded by the server's networking stack (which is expected behavior for UDP).

If you want to receive most or all of the UDP packets, you'll need to code your server in such a way that it always calls `recvfrom()` in a timely manner, so that it can pull incoming UDP packets out of the socket's receive-buffer before that buffer fills up.  (Note that even then it's not guaranteed that you'll receive all of the data, since UDP packets can be dropped for other reasons as well).

One way to do that would be to handle network and audio playback in separate threads on your server, so that the audio playback doesn't hold off the network-data-reception.  Alternatively, you might be able to multiplex the two streams using `select()` or similar (depending on how PyAudio is implemented; I've never used that API so I can't say for sure).

Alternatively, you could slow down your client so that it sends audio at the same rate the server consumes it (i.e. 22050*4 bytes per second, or whatever it works out to be), although even that would only help for short audio files, since eventually the audio will either underrun or overrun on the server side due to clock drift, etc.

Comment: So the server doesn t actually speeds up the replay but some packets get lost and it sounds like a speed up. Corect?. With this in mind here comes another question. How does this protocol gets used in video streaming for example where the rendering must take some time meanwhile the udp is firing packages and get lost because the server is busy doing the rendering. If i am the client that sends frames of a video while i stream, how can the server on the other side keep up ?

Comment: Right, audio is skipped/dropped.  In video streaming, the client sends feedback to the server letting the server know to speed up or slow down its transmission as necessary (e.g. if the client's internal buffer is getting too full, it tells the server to slow down; if it's getting close to empty, it tells the server to speed up).  Note that TCP handles this issue for you automatically.